# Unpivot con nombre de Columnas

Tags: sql-server

Estoy importando mediante C# un archivo Excel de forma tabular, pero necesito hacer un Unpivot con los nombres de las columnas como registros y sus valores en otra columna aquí una imagen de como esta la tabla con sus datos:

[image: Tabla Usuario]

Y aquí una imagen del resultado que busco:

[image: UnPivot]

Para ello estoy tratando con este Query sql que encontre en la WEB ero no me queda, me da este error:
**'un' has fewer columns than were specified in the column list.**

```
SELECT IdCod, Cod, Estado, idApliacion, ColumnName, ValColumn 
FROM DatosUsuario
CROSS JOIN (
VALUES ('TextA'),('TextB'),('TextC'),('TextD'),('TextE')
) un(ColumnName, ValColumn)
```

Agrego nueva imagen con errores:
[image: Errores Sentencia]

Que es lo que tengo mal en la query, ya tengo agregadas todas las columnas?

Answer (score 2):

El problema del query original es que te falta agregar una columna a tu instrucción `VALUES`. Es importante conocer como funciona el código que encuentras en internet. `APPLY` es similar a un `JOIN` pero con la capacidad de hacer uso de las columnas de las tablas anteriores para generar tablas derivadas. Las tablas derivadas pueden ser subqueries o, en este caso, se pueden crear con la instrucción VALUES.

```
SELECT IdCod, Cod, Estado, idApliacion, ColumnName, ValColumn 
FROM DatosUsuario
CROSS JOIN (
            VALUES ('TextA', TextA), --cada conjunto de parentesis representa una fila
                   ('TextB', TextB), --la primer columna es el nombre
                   ('TextC', TextC), --la segunda columna es el valor que viene de DatosUsuario
                   ('TextD', TextD),
                   ('TextE', TextE)
                            ) un(ColumnName, ValColumn); --Aquí nombras 2 columnas
```

Este método es mi favorito puesto que permite una mayor flexibilidad al convertir columnas a filas.

Comment: Gracias por comentar,
Tengo un par de dudas,
('TextA', TextA), --cada conjunto de paréntesis representa una fila, entendido
('TextB', TextB), --la primer columna es el nombre, nombre de la columna en la tabla Sql?
('TextC', TextC), --la segunda columna es el valor que viene de DatosUsuario, el valor que viene dentro de la columna?
que pasa si la columna tiene distintos valores?
Trate de hacer uso de tu sentencia, pero me esta dando errores, publique una imagen con los errores.
@Luis Cazares

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución:

```
select u.IdCod, u.Cod, u.ValColumn, u.ColumnName, u.Estado, u.idApicacion
from DatosUsuarios
unpivot
(


ColumnName
  for ValColumn in (TextA, TextB, TextC, TextD, TextE)

) u;
```